# Chrome doesn't work properly on keycode/keypress (JQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a data insertion in excel-like environment (the idea is to upload the data copypasting from excel).

I'm using JQuery for this, and works pretty well in Firefox, but Chrome is a headache on keypress, I really don't get how to make it work.

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/j6PgY/

What I'm doing is something like this:

```
$(document).live('keypress', function(e){
if(e.keyCode==38 && y!=1){ // Up
    y--;
}else if(e.keyCode==40 && y!=largo){ // Down
    y++;
}
```

Take a look from line 67

Comment: You lost me at "...from line 67"... Yikes!

Comment: And why would you need live() on the document? It's always available ?

Comment: `but Chrome is a headache, I really don't get how to make it work.` What exactly is not working? Can you please calrify this as once the fiddle goes dead this question will make no sense and has no value to future users with possible similar issues. Try to have a complete question, posting the relevant code and stating the exact problems which does not rely on anyone having to look at a link which is dead in the near future.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, use `which` rather than `keyCode` - these two properties can vary from browser to browser, but jQuery normalises the `which` property for you.

Comment: @adeneo This is because it will charge data dinamically, later.

Comment: The document is never dynamic ?

Comment: @FrancoisWahl Ok, I've edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which==38 && y!=1){ // Up
        y--;
    }else if(e.which==40 && y!=largo){ // Down
        y++;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6PgY/1/)

Replacing `keypress` with `keydown` does the trick. It's also not neccessary to use `live()` or other delegated event handlers on the document, as it's not dynamic, it's actually always available. And `e.which` is normalized in jQuery.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot.The live() is useful for example when I call the addX() function.

Comment: @AlanArellano: `live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. If you need binding to dynamic elements you can use `on` with delegation : i.e: `$(document).on('keydown', '#idofdynamicelement', function(){// your usual code})`. Even though `live()` since 1.7 is using `on()` under the hood it is recommended to use `on` since 1.7. Also saves you a lot of hassle when upgrading to 1.9 not relying on migrate-js to fill the gaps of removed features, etc..

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I didn't change "live" per "on" because of troubles with pasting data. And live was available on this JQuery version. Maybe I will migrate this when I'll have time, thanks :)